# JSoup From String to Int

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I worked with JSoup in android studio. In my code i have this:

```
Elements description = document.select("something");
```

*if i do this -*

```
String foo = description.text();
```

everything works fine.

*But if i do this -*

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(description.text());
```

Why does my app crash?

All my code:

```
public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup
                    .connect("something")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko")
                    .get();
            Elements description = document.select("something");

            String foo = description.text();
            int fuu = Integer.parseInt(foo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: wild guess: description.text() is not a valid integer

Comment: Try: Integer.parseInt(description.text().toString());

Comment: What precisely `description.text()` returns to you? Consider adding something like `System.out.println("["+description.text()+"]");` to see if there are any additional characters like spaces.

Comment: Pshemo, description.text() returns "65".

Comment: Antonio Balduzzi, it doesnt work

Comment: Reimeus, description.text() its just "65" but in string "form".

Comment: Are you sure that there are no spaces or hidden haracters? Try with `String text = description.text(); System.out.println("["+text+"]->"+text.length());`. Is result `[65]->2`?

Comment: Oh, and if you want to respond to someones comment try adding in your response `@nickOfThatPerson`. This way notification of your response will be sent to that person. In my case you can start your comment with @Pshemo.

Comment: @Pshemo, yeah result is [65]->2.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the HTML and the way you're extracting it?

Comment: is the problem solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty much impossible to say what it is going on in your code without the Stack Trace and the original HTML or URL. However, I see one possibility for the crash, that is that the string does not contain a valid number. Since you state that the printout of the string actaully prints out "65" I can only assume that the string may be using strange uft8 unicode characters that look like or are numbers but can't be interpreted by Integer.parseInt(String).

For example, if your input string is "" it may look like "65" but it is unicode using U+1D7FC (MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE DIGIT SIX) and U+1D7FB    (MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE DIGIT FIVE)

A list of such number characters in unicode can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)

A work around ([suggested in the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813135/why-does-integer-parseint-ud835-udfe8-fail)) may be to use the [Normalizer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html):

```
String numberStr = Normalizer.normalize(description.text(), Form.NFKC);
Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try `int foo = Integer.parse(description.ownText());`