# Why does Integer.parseInt("\uD835\uDFE8") fail?

Tags: java, unicode, integer, string-parsing

I was under the impression that java supports unicode characters. I made this test and sadly found that it fails. The question is why? Is it a bug or somewhere documented?

```
// MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF ""
String unicodeNum6 = "\uD835\uDFE8";
int codePoint6 = unicodeNum6.codePointAt(0);    
int val6 = Character.getNumericValue(codePoint6);
System.out.println("unicodeNum6 = "+ unicodeNum6
    + ", codePoint6 = "+ codePoint6+ ", val6 = "+val6);
int unicodeNum6Int = Integer.parseInt(unicodeNum6);
```

This fails with a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Unexpected I think, since the println works and prints the expected line:

```
unicodeNum6 = , codePoint6 = 120808, val6 = 6
```

So Java perfectly knows the numerical value of the unicode character but does not use it in parseInt.

Can someone give a good reason why it should fail?

Comment: It is worth noting that you can run this string through the `Normalizer.normalize()` and then the `Integer.parseInt()` will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not bug, the behaviour is documented. According to the documentation for [parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine)

> The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix
>   (**as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a
>   nonnegative value)**, except that the first character may be an ASCII
>   minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII
>   plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value

If you try :

```
int aa = Character.digit('\uD835', 10);
int bb = Character.digit('\uDFE8', 10);
```

You'll see that both return -1.
Mind you, `Integer.parseInt(unicodeNum6);` will just call `Integer.parseInt(unicodeNum6, 10);`